# Overflow auto with inline content without scrollbar

Tags: html, overflow, font-size, css

I'm trying to overflow: auto a p-tag at a specific max-height. But if the p-tag is smaller than the max-height, a scrollbar is still visibile.

I tested in all webkit-browsers and internet explorer. and it's always the same. Except Firefox renders well.

This is my Code. I created a jsfiddle for testing.

```
<p>test</p>


p {
  font-family: sans-serif; 
  font-size: 50px; 
  line-height: 50px; 
  overflow: auto;
  max-height: 200px }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7jZLj/4/

i tried with -webkit-padding-after and it seems to work sometimes.

so, are there any fixes or workarounds?

thx for your help.

andré

Comment: you can safely remove line-height i believe, font-size sets the default line-height itself  http://jsfiddle.net/7jZLj/6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this

```
p {    
  line-height: normal; 
  }
```

Here is the **[link](http://jsfiddle.net/kiranm/7jZLj/7/)**

Answer (score 0):

Update your class like below.

```
 p {
   font-family: sans-serif; 
   font-size: 50px; 
   line-height:auto; 
   overflow: auto;
   max-height: 200px;
  }
```

Comment: i think this only works if there is no line-height defined in any parent elements

Answer (score 0):

Giving the `<p>` a 3px padding seems to solve your problem